# When I use nvim, blank display only red. How to solve this problem?

Tags: neovim

Nvim breaks the color of white space.

I did it with `vim.opt.termguicolors = true` in nvim init.lua.
But the colors don't look right in my old oh-my-zsh.

The weird thing is that if I run nvim in a shell with tmux, it works fine. I don't know why.
Is there a solution?

Below is my lua file.
After that is an example of what happens when I try to use my old zsh shell.
Last is the result of running the shell through tmux and then running nvim.

Here is my setting lua file:

```lua
local o = vim.o
vim.opt.cursorline = true      --show current cursor line
if vim.opt.termguicolors then
  vim.opt.termguicolors = true --use true color -> true color is wide color of standard 257 color in vim
else
  vim.opt.termguicolors = false
end

vim.opt.winblend    = 0 -- option controls the transparency of floating windows.(like lsp command gp window)
-- when you're typing file names or directory paths in Vim's command-line.
-- p - Show the preview window when multiple matches are found
-- u - Auto-insert characters that can complete the match
-- m - Show matches in a pop-up menu
vim.opt.wildoptions = 'pum'
-- set transparency popup
vim.opt.pumblend    = 5
vim.opt.background  = 'dark'

-- blew is base.lua
vim.cmd('autocmd!')        -- remove auto cmd (after clear and start setting)
vim.scriptencoding = 'utf-8'
vim.opt.encoding = 'utf-8' -- user interface encoding
vim.opt.fileencoding = 'utf-8'

vim.wo.number = true                             -- display line num
vim.opt.title = true                             -- set title of ternimal window to file name
vim.opt.autoindent = true                        -- if you enter newline cursor automatically move indent level
vim.opt.hlsearch = true                          --  search highlighting
vim.opt.backup = false                           -- not use backup
vim.opt.showcmd = true                           -- display last cmd after exit command mode
vim.opt.cmdheight = 1                            -- display cmd line height
vim.opt.laststatus = 2                           -- 2 is alway show bottom status
vim.opt.expandtab = true                         -- change tab to sevral space
vim.opt.scrolloff = 10                           -- keep screen number below and above

vim.opt.backupskip = '/tmp/*,/private/tmp/*'     -- skip backup when file locate "/tmp/*" and "/private/tmp/*"
vim.opt.icm = 'split'                            -- method to enter Non ASCII character
vim.opt.ignorecase = true                        -- when search for text
vim.opt.smarttab = true                          -- when press tab-key , based on the existing indentation of the current line.
vim.opt.breakindent = true                       -- whether vim adds extra indentation to wrapped lines of text.
vim.opt.shiftwidth = 2                           -- '>>' '<<' press set line
vim.opt.tabstop = 2                              -- control tab the number of space
vim.opt.ai = true                                -- Auto indent when press 'enter'
vim.opt.si = true                                -- Smart indent based space lever like '{}'
vim.opt.wrap = true                              -- if text line is very long to fit within current monitor width, fit or not
vim.opt.mouse = ''                               -- set no use mouse in vim
vim.opt.backspace =
'start,eol,indent'                               --if press 'backspace' when position beginning-line, move to end of previous line ,cuntinue delete
vim.opt.path:append { '**' }                     -- Finding files - Search down into subfolders
vim.opt.wildignore:append { '*/node_modules/*' } -- ignore subfolders 'node_modules'

-- Turn off paste mode when leaving insert
-- nopaste is set pastemode off -> This will disable certain features like autoindenting and mappings, which can prevent unintended side effects while pasting.
vim.cmd([[let &t_Cs = "\e[4:3m" ]])
vim.cmd([[let &t_Ce = "\e[4:0m"]])

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("InsertLeave", {
  pattern = '*',
  command = "set nopaste"
})

-- Add asterisks in block comments
-- create insert a closing bracket or quote
vim.opt.formatoptions:append { 'r' }
```

[image: without tmux]

[image: with tmux]

Comment: if vim.opt.termguicolors then
  vim.opt.termguicolors = true
else
  vim.opt.termguicolors = false
end This looks wrong: it says if the variable is true, make it true. That's a no-op, and might be what's causing the problem. You need to set `termguicolors` if-and-only-if the underlying terminal emulator supports truecolor

Comment: I would "Debug" this by commenting out `vim.opt.background` & then commenting out the `paste-mode` stuff. BTW , it is not white-space here. It is just the Part outside the "Editable Area" , you should Insert new-lines , spaces & tabs in the "Editable Area" to check what you get.

Comment: D.Ben Knoble => I corrected the code, but it still indicates the problem.
What does it mean if the underlying terminal emulator supports truecolor?
I'm using the default terminal app on a mac.
But in that terminal app, inside a shell with tmux, nvim's theme works fine.
It doesn't work in oh-my-zsh, which is not tmux.

_Prem_ => When I insert enter, space inside the editable area, the black background comes out fine. In the non-editable area, it appears red. It also appears with background=dark.

Comment: I ran it with the same terminal emulator and was wondering why it works fine with tmux but not with the default shell (oh-my-zsh).
Isn't the shell that tmux runs the same oh-my-zsh?

I don't know why the two modern ones would make a difference.

Comment: Looks like you've found the trouble spot.
`curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnMorales/dotfiles/master/colors/24-bit-color.sh | bash`
When I run the above syntax in TMUX, the colors come out fine.
However, when I run it in the default terminal (not tmux), the colors don't come out well. What should I check?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure because I can't reproduce your problem but I would pay particular attention to the following:

- The `wincolor` color that contains an alternative highlight group to color Normal
- The `Terminal` highlighting groups

A test worth doing is probably:

```
set wincolor=
highlight! link Terminal Normal
```